# WebSocket progress

Tags: html, websocket, progress

I have a case where I may need to send 500KB - 1MB of data to the client via WebSockets. Therefore, I was wondering if it was possible to track the progress of how much data has been received by the client. That way the application does not appear to be non-responsive when connecting via a slower connection.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way to do this.  (That is, while the websocket protocol allows for fragmentation of messages, any client using Javascript's websocket API has no access to this and is only informed when a browser receives all message fragments and combines their contents into a single buffer.)

You could indicate progress in application code however by breaking your single large message into several smaller ones.

If you do this, you'll also need to define your own simple protocol.  At a minimum, this could be an initial message that informs the client that following messages are to be combined and add up to x bytes.  Or, if you don't know the size of data in advance, a second message that follows the final data transfer and indicates the end of your fragmented message.